# Split tsrange to days in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How can I split a tsrange like `[2020-06-09 14:30, 2020-06-12 15:30)` to days ?

```
+------------------+------------------+
|      start       |       end        |
+------------------+------------------+
| 2020-06-09 14:30 | 2020-06-09 24:00 |
| 2020-06-10 00:00 | 2020-06-10 24:00 |
| 2020-06-11 00:00 | 2020-06-11 24:00 |
| 2020-06-12 00:00 | 2020-06-12 15:30 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Join with `generate_series`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you explain more , How exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I can't provide you the complete code snippet, but hope pseudo-code may help,

- STEP 1: Create a *[function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/)* that accepts **startTs** and **endTs** as parameters
- STEP 2: The function should return multiple rows, you can get info here, [how to create function that returns set of rows](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions)
- STEP 3: In this function loop until, date of startTs and endTs aren't same with help of `EXTRACT(DAY from DATE(startTs))`
- STEP 4: In every iteration (considering you are using table) INSERT a row in your new table with startTs and startTs with end of day time i.e. 23:59:59 and set startTs to start of day time of next day.
- STEP 5: When DAY of startTs is same as DAY OF endTs, then add startTs and endTs in that table

Now rows in your table, is your solution.

Happy Coding :)